# notify() is not working in IE8

Tags: sproutcore

I am working on a web app based on Sproutcore 1.9.1. To retrieve data from server it 
    makes a SC.Request.getUrl() request, which works fine in all the browsers except IE8.
    For IE8 when the request is like this:

```
    SC.Request.getUrl("'http://example.com/some/path')
    .set('isJSON', YES)
    .async(false)        // made async false to work in IE
    .notify(this, 'someMethodDidComplete', {  query: query, store: store})
    .send();

works fine. But when the request is :

    SC.Request.getUrl("'http://example.com/some/path')
    .set('isJSON', YES)
    .notify(this, 'someMethodDidComplete', {  query: query, store: store})
    .send();

it works fine for other browsers but for IE8, it is not working. After spending some 
time with the issue i found out that the finishrequest() is not invoking. For doing so 
what I did is made 'asynchronous false' and then it works.  Now I don't know what to do. 
Please suggest me something on this and  why normal request is not working.
thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known (https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/issues/866) and seems to be fixed, at least on SC master.

As a side note, you include the query and store in an object as parameter to .notify(). You don't need to do this, you can simply include them as extra parameters and your notify function will be called with those extra parameters:

```
.notify(this,this.notifier,query,store)
```

and somewhere else in the file:

```
notifier: function(result,query,store){ }
```